# How to include scope variables options array with values in angulajs?

Tags: html, angularjs

I am very new to AngularJS.
I have query on how to to have a drop down that have scope variable options which contains Low Price to High and High Price to Low values in it.

Also sort the product list based on the price (higher to lower / lower to higher).

Answer (score 0):

I created demo for you with what you are looking.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/almogKashany/n3b0mrz7/5/)

You can see that angularJs give you option `OrderBy: 'key'` you can choose how to tell angular sorted current repeat.

For now its sort by higher to lower but if you want the oposite you can remove  the `true` from the `orderBy` filter

Comment: Thanks almog kashany. It was very much helpful to carry out further on my learning in angularjs.

Comment: @Chethan you welcome, you can up-vote that its answer for your question